# How to respond to state change in redux and dispatch another action?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Can someone give me clues on how to do the following with react-redux:

Component A dispatches an action that updates the state (async)

Component B (not a child component of A) needs to be able to detect when the state changes and dispatch another action.

My problem is when I try do dispatch action 2 in component B, the state is still in the initial state and it is not updated.

I also have tried dispatching action 2 in componentWillUpdate, however, that creates an infinite loop because the second action also updates the state (and also asynchronously)

This is how it looks like, more or less:

```
//----- Component A
class ComponentA extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.props.dispatch(loadEvents()); // loadEvents is async and will   update state.eventsState
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = function (state) {
  return {
    eventsState: state.eventsState,
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ComponentA);


//----- Component B
class ComponentA extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    props.dispatch(getEventUsers(props.eventsState.eventId)); // the eventsState is in initial state here (empty)...where do I call getEventUsers?
  }

  componentWillUpdate(nextProps) {
    nextProps.dispatch(getEventUsers(props.eventsState.eventId)) // Creates an infinite loop, getEventUsers also updates state
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = function (state) {
  return {
    eventsState: state.eventsState,
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ComponentA);
```

Comment: Component B should just take into account the time between starting load and load being done. It could show a spinner or nothing (empty div). Even if your `loadEvents` reducer is synchronous, there's no guarantee it gets dispatched first. React alone decides when it calls various functions like `shouldComponentUpdate` and even your component constructors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without looking at your Redux code, I'd say your Component B is getting empty data in the constructor because it's instantiated at about the same time a Component A, and at that point the async request initiated by Component A constructor is still in progress.

Your Redux should fire an action that contains the received data when the async request completes. Your reducer then puts this data in the state, which in turn changes the props of your connected components and forces them to rerender.

You should dispatch getEventUsers only when props.eventState.eventId exists and has changed.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks! How would you check that props.eventState.eventId exists? Should I just compare nextProps to this.props in componentWillUpdate ?

Comment: The problem with just comparing this.props to nextProps is that if your eventUsers are contained in your eventState you'll get a new eventState reference when you load users, so they will be different, even though the event is the same, causing eventUsers to be fetched again. Comparing the id makes sure that you are really looking at a different event. This might be a problem if you do want to reload the data for the same event at some point. I'd suggest normalizing your state: keep all loaded users in a separate object mapping their IDs to user data, then refer to them by ID in event objects.